# Checking for exceptions in DTO - best practice

Tags: c#, exception

Consider a two dimensional Matrix class which has an overloaded indexer, sth like this:

```
public class Matrix
{
    private readonly double[,] _matrix;

    public double this[int i, int j]
    {
        get
        {
            return _matrix[i, j];
        }
        set
        {
            _matrix[i, j] = value;
        }
    }

    public double this[int i, int j]
    {
        get
        {
            if (i < 0 || i >= _matrix.GetLength(0) || j < 0 || j >= _matrix.GetLength(1))
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("index was out of range");

            return _matrix[i, j];
        }
        set
        {
            if (i < 0 || i >= _matrix.GetLength(0) || j < 0 || j >= _matrix.GetLength(1))
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("index was out of range");
            _matrix[i, j] = value;
        }
    }

    public double this[int i, int j]
    {
        get
        {
            if (i < 0 || i >= _matrix.GetLength(0) || j < 0 || j >= _matrix.GetLength(1))
                return 0;
            return _matrix[i, j];
        }
        set
        {
            if (i >= 0 || i < _matrix.GetLength(0) || j >= 0 || j < _matrix.GetLength(1))
                _matrix[i, j] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

as you see there are 3 versions of indexer.

1) this version doesn't check indexes

2) this version checks indexes and if they're out of dimensions throw's IndexOutOfRangeException

3) this version checks indexes and assigns/returns values only if indexes are valid.

So my question is which of them is the best practice to use? What would you prefer and why? or may I create a new custom exception like "MatrixIndexOutOfRange" and throw it instead of IndexOutOfRange exception?

Answer (score 1):

If the values you are getting are unexpected and you don't know what to do: throw an exception.

If the values you are getting are unexpected and you know what to do: do it.

If you have to throw an exception, throw the most meaningful exception possible. ie. if from a business perspective (ie. the job of your class) it makes sense to throw a custom exception then do it. Otherwise, you're fine with the usual `OutOfRangeException`.

Answer (score 1):

Version (1) is the best.

The array `double[,]` will itself throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException`, so I don't see any value in doing this test yourself.

And silently accepting invalid parameters (version 3) is fragile in my view.

Answer (score 1):

Version 1 and 2 will give you the same behavoir, so version 1 is better because it is less code. If you whould go for version 2 you should also add a null check and throw a exception if the matrix is null, and maybe more checks which will fail in version 1.

Version 3 will just hide any programming errors you make and will cost you a lot of time when debugging. In a code review I would definitly change the code to version 1.